# How to construct features for LightGBM for discovering a property?

Tags: cart

I'm using lightgbm on time series data to solve regression problem,  I learned that I can construct new features, such as Shift and diff features for target, how does that actually help to make the model has a smaller Mean Square Error? I guess the model discovers properties in data such as cyclic property through these features, but I failed to give a clear explanation.

Comment: what new features create depends on your data and on your problem. instead, it doesn't depend much on your learning algorithm (lightGBM)

Comment: @carlo, that's not really true — a relationship will be learned more easily if it can be expressed in terms of the basis functions your model is using. For instance, if you are using an OLS approach to learn the relationship E(Y) = X^2 then it will fit far better if you make X^2 as a feature as well as X. If you were using regression trees then the effect on the MSE would be much less.